# Linq Is not working fine not getting any data in Ajax My Linq Query attached

Tags: asp.net-mvc, linq, model-view-controller, linq-to-entities, asp.net-ajax

I have two Tables one is "Questions" and second is "SurveyQuestion"

```
Questions has four column ID , Text, QuestionType, Options
```

and

```
SurveyQuestion has four column ID, SuerveyID , QuestionID, OrderID
```

I have Survey ID now trying to use LINQ and get all value from Question Table,

My Method calling from Ajax is in Controller that is,

```
public ActionResult Index(string prefix)
{
    List<SelectList> Questions = new List<SelectList>();

    //  Here "MyDatabaseEntities " is dbContext, which is created at time of model creation.
    SurveyAppEntities ObjectSur = new SurveyAppEntities();
    // Questions = ObjectSur.Surveys.Where(a => a.ID.Equals(prefix)).toToList();

    var e = from q in ObjectSur.Questions
            join b in ObjectSur.SurveyQuestions on q.ID equals b.QuestionID
            where b.SurveyID.Equals(prefix)
            select q;
    return Json(e, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

Ajax Cal and this method returning data process is working fine because i tried just to pass string and after changing that string i am getting in ajax alert but when use this linq not sending any result

Hopes for your suggestions

```
Ajax Call:

    function MyFunction() {
        alert($('#DDlSurvey').val());
        $.ajax({
            url: "@Url.Action("Index", "ConductSurvey")",
            data: { prefix: $('#DDlSurvey').val() },
            type: "POST",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (data) {
                //  loadData(data);
                alert(data)
                alert("Success");
            },
            error: function () {
                alert("Failed! Please try again.");
            }
        });
        //$('#YourLabelId').val('ReplaceWithThisValue');
    }
```

Comment: Could you post your javascript code containing the ajax call?

Comment: @akerra post updated

Comment: Have you verified that your controller action is getting hit by using a breakpoint? I notice your AJAX call specifies POST, but I don't see `[HttpPost]` above your action.

Comment: Brother i am using post in controller hit by break point but linq is not working fine

Comment: your variable `e` is an `IQueryable`. Try returning `Json(e.ToList(), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet)` so that the query gets executed.

Comment: It does not have .toList() option :(

Comment: Try include `System.Linq` namespace, you should be able to see it.

Comment: i have added it

Answer (score 0):

I hope this will help you.

```
 var e = (from q in ObjectSur.Questions
        join b in ObjectSur.SurveyQuestions on q.ID equals b.QuestionID
        where b.SurveyID.Equals(prefix)
        select q).ToList()
```